# Get SVG positionning X and Y from latitude and longitude

Tags: math, svg, position, logic

This is basically more of a logical and arithmetic problem than pure programming : I have an SVG drawing in my webpage (the map of France) where I want to position a blue dot as a nested SVG. The dot is a `<circle r="10.7"/>`.

The blue dot represents a place for which I possess both the latitude and longitude coordinates.

I know that the center of the map has the following SVG coordinates :

```
<circle cx="103.5" cy="103.5"> // outer circle
```

The blue dot SVG tag is, therefore, positionned as such :

```
<svg x="92.8" y="92.8"> // blue dot svg tag
```

Those values are calculated like so : `103.5 - 10.7 = 92.8` that are the center of the map minus the radius of the blue dot. So it is perfectly centered as such :

[image: minimap]

I have roughly gotten the latitude and longitude coordinates of the center of France thanks to one of the multiple website that allow this operation. Those are :

```
Latitude : 46.561941
Longitude : 2.468983
```

So I know that

```
46.561941 = 92.8
 2.468983 = 92.8
```

Therefore, I was wondering to get some help to calculate the correspondance between those two values that would make me able to position the blue dot wherever I need to, given new latitude and longitude coordinates.

I sense that a simple rule 3 would not suffice (I've given that a try already). Also, I need to take the `10.7` circle radius into account.

What would be the new `x` and `y` SVG positionning values for, let's say, those new coordinates ?

```
Latitude : 43.227284
Longitude : 3.243921
```

Also, the whole SVG viewport is `(207, 207)` and the outer SVG tag has `width="90px"` and `height="90px"`.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @HighPerformanceMark, thanks for commenting! I'll give that a try but I doubt it'll work. And yeah, that was the exact purpose of the first sentence of my question. Thanks again!

Comment: It is actually not that simple. You need to know the projection method of the map to be able to reproduce it. [Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) is a projection where the mapping to x/y coordinates is pretty simple. But there are others.

Comment: This is certainly a case for using a library for drawing maps that do the whole projection math for you. Notable for SVG is [tag:d3.js], especially [d3-geo](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo)

Comment: @D4V1D did you find a solution? If yes, please post an answer.